# Magento export orders via API - SOAP using sales_order.info method

Tags: api, magento

The sales_order.info method allows to retrieve the required order information like
product-sku or costumer-id and many other.

But how can i add my own created attributs to this method so i can get these via API SOAP ?

Thanks for helpul answers!

Comment: Done.  I've created a new Column with this attribute in sales_flat_order_item and added this attribute to several .php in mage_sales_order.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to get another attributes when You call sales_order.info, You must edit/rewrite

```
Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Api.php
```

As far as i know. the API get all attributes of 'sales/order' model.

add your attribute to $result
Example:

```
$result['your attribute'] = $this->_getAttributes($yourattribute, 'attribute_name');
```

^^

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below SOAP api script for get the order list

```
<?php 
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->call($session, 'order.list');

var_dump ($result);
```